# Efficient estimation of logistic regression

Tags: r, optimization, logistic-regression, linear-programming

For a better understanding of inner workings and a simple road to further experimentation, I'm trying to implement a (regularized) logistic regression on R.

It is known that one way of implementing it is by solving the following problem:

$$ \arg \min_{\beta} \sum(-y_i ( x_i' \beta)  + log(1 + e^{x_i' \beta})) + \lambda \|\beta\| $$

However, for any larger value of $x_i' \beta$ the `exp` explodes, returning an `Inf` value. One solution that I have found is by using `Rmpfr::mpfr` and adding some precision, i.e.,

```
x <- mpfr(x, precBits = 106)
```

But this adds quite an overhead performance wise. On the other hand, base implementation of `glm` or `glmnet` manages to get the solution rather quickly. How is it so? What are the possible ways of avoiding the calculation of `exp(x %*% beta)`? Or is this achieved only by reducing to some other implementation, i.e., in C or Fortran?

**Note:**
I'm trying to do this using `Rsolnp::solnp` Augmented Lagrangian optimizer with certain constraints on the parameters. For simple regression problems this seems OK performance wise due to the ability to add a gradient, however for logistic regression this might not be too great?

```
Rsolnp:::solnp(pars = beta0, fun = logistic_optimizer,  
                     eqfun = constraint,
                     ineqfun = positive_constraint,
                     ineqLB = rep(0, length(beta0)),
                     ineqUB =rep(Inf, length(beta0)),
                     LB = rep(0, length(beta0)),
                     UB = rep(Inf, length(beta0))
                     )
```

It would be nice to know if there are more efficient ways to manually solve this, without reducing to known libraries such as `glm` or `glmnet`, since I want the control over `logistic_optimizer` expression.

Comment: Just a comment that, if you aren't doing that yet, you may want to try to standardize your data first.

Comment: This helps in most cases, I just though that, unless ``glm`` is doing that somewhere inside the code, there might be a solution without standardization. ``glmnet`` with ``standardize=FALSE`` also doesn't break.

Comment: Anyway, in both cases I'm getting a ``Problem Inverting Hessian``, even though ``det(cov(x))`` is not bad and ``glm`` is also fine with it. Probably will have to re-ask the question for the Hessian. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check out the function `optim {stats}`. See this post for a LASSO implementation:

[How can I implement lasso in R using optim function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121209/how-can-i-implement-lasso-in-r-using-optim-function)

and for a GLM implementation:

[Applying Cost Functions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372821/applying-cost-functions-in-r/42374307)

In addition, `optim` is written partly in Mortran (extension of Fortran), so it will not be that easy to modify the `optim` functions for custom functions, unless you are a Fortran Wizard.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Still, for the LASSO part, can we actually do it with ``optim``? As far as I know, due to the nature of LASSO penalty, we need to split ``beta`` into ``beta_pos = (beta + abs(beta)) / 2`` and ``beta_neg = (beta -abs(beta)) / 2`` to ensure differentiability, thus requiring additional constraints. Didn't find such constraints on ``optim``